# How to create a pivot view in MariaDB from json keys?

Tags: pivot, mariadb

I have a table like this:

```
   +--------+--------------+-----------------------+
   | hostid |   hostName   |        attr           |
   +--------+----------+---------------------------+
   |   1    |    host1     |  {"cpu": 1, "ram": 2} |
   +--------+--------------+-----------------------+
   |   2    |    host2     |  {"cpu": 2, "ram": 1} |
   +--------+--------------+-----------------------+
   |   3    |    host3     |  {"cpu": 1, "ram": 5} |
   +--------+--------------+-----------------------+
   |   4    |    host4     |  {"cpu": 3, "ram": 7} |
   +--------+--------------+-----------------------+
```

I would like to create a view that show a table like this, where the columns was taken from "attr" column (json keys):

```
   +--------+--------------+-----------+
   | hostid |   hostName   | cpu | ram |
   +--------+----------+---------------+
   |   1    |    host1     |  1  |  2  | 
   +--------+--------------+-----------+
   |   2    |    host2     |  2  |  1  |
   +--------+--------------+-----------+
   |   3    |    host3     |  1  |  5  |
   +--------+--------------+-----------+
   |   4    |    host4     |  3  |  7  |
   +--------+--------------+-----------+
```

How I can create a view like this? the complexity is in auto discover the json keys.

Comment: JSON is good --- for stuff you don't need to break apart.